# Python class type usage before created

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, types, metaclass

I need class with possibility of create other class instances and self instances in class method scope. I have following code:

```
class A:
    #somme stuff

class B:
    allowed_children_types = [ #no reason to make self.allowed_children_types
        A,
        C #first problem, no C know
    ]

    @staticmethod
    def foo(self):
        #use allowed_children_types to create children objects


class C:
    allowed_children_types = [  # no reason to make self.allowed_children_types
        A,
        B
        C  # second problem, no C know because type object is not yet created
    ]

    @staticmethod
    def foo(self):
        #use allowed_children_types to create children objects
```

I will not create independent factory because it will complicated very simple application logic. I feel that create custom metaclass is usually bad designe.

What should I do to jump over this issue?

Comment: You can only refer to a name if it has been defined. After you class definitions, assign the class variables

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please provide information about what you actually want to do. Why can't you use a `classmethod`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have all those names defined before you use them. Something like:

```
class A:
    #somme stuff

class B:

    @staticmethod
    def foo(self):
        #use allowed_children_types to create children objects


class C:

    @staticmethod
    def foo(self):
        #use allowed_children_types to create children objects

B.allowed_children_types = [A, C]
C.allowed_children_types = [A, B, C]
```

Comment: Dirty solution (i want a bit more clean solution) but enough for me.